# Suppress validation errors in ASP.NET Core's automatic 400 response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

Although the [automatic 400 response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses) is useful, I don't want to send validation errors to the client.

This is the response body:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "username": [
      "'username' must not be empty."
    ],
    ...more errors
  },
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "xxx:yyy"
}
```

But what I want is the default, without the errors:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "xxx:yyy"
}
```

I thought all I needed to do was set

```
options.SuppressUseValidationProblemDetailsForInvalidModelStateResponses = true;
```

...but that doesn't do anything.

I don't want to disable this feature, I just want to suppress validation errors. How do I do that?

---

BTW, I am using a workaround, by creating the response body manually, but I'd prefer to avoid this:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(apiBehaviorOptions => {
  apiBehaviorOptions.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext => {
    var pd    = new ProblemDetails();
    pd.Type   = apiBehaviorOptions.ClientErrorMapping[400].Link;
    pd.Title  = apiBehaviorOptions.ClientErrorMapping[400].Title;
    pd.Status = 400;
    pd.Extensions.Add("traceId", actionContext.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);
    return new BadRequestObjectResult(pd);
  };
});
```

Comment: A 400 means the request itself is bad. What you call a workaround is the documented way of customizing the 400 response. It's *not* a workaround. That's explained in the link you posted in your own question

Comment: What is your Compatibility version (as set by `SetCompatibilityVersion`)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I thought that `SuppressUseValidationProblemDetailsForInvalidModelStateResponses` was the way to do it, but it doesn't work for me. It's available for a reason, but I can't seem to get it to work. BTW I agree that 400 isn't the best for invalid data, but that's how the framework does it, I would use 422.

Comment: @ESG `CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Problem details" corresponds to RFC 7807, which is an attempt at standardizing the way HTTP APIs report errors. `SuppressUseValidationProblemDetailsForInvalidModelStateResponses` does not cover specifically the returning of the actual validation errors, just the standard bits discussed in the RFC.

The only way to do what you want is what you've already done, i.e. using a custom factory. It's not a hack or a workaround: that is the documented way to alter the automatic response.

That said, it makes absolutely zero sense to suppress the validation errors. The whole entire point is to inform the client about what mistakes were present in the request so that the client can correct those mistakes. Without that, you're just slamming the door, without any indication of what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Then it's a weirdly named property - but thanks for confirming my approach is suitable. BTW I found no way to share validation logic between the angular client and server, so I had created extensive validation on the client, and saw no reason to link the two... (once upon a time that would have been easy with jquery validate)

Comment: Well, first, client-side validation should always be a progressive enhancement, not your be-all-end-all plan. Server-side validation is the only thing you can trust. Once you've hit the server, it's validation errors overrule anything happening client-side. Also, you should not be building an API purely to support an Angular app. That may be what it's for, but the API should function well, no matter what client is utilizing it. If you later need to do something from a mobile app, you're going to have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with ProblemDetails is that it is the default response for the StatusCodeResult with ths StatusCode greater or equal to 400.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The following action generates a response with ProblemDetails if the status is greater or equal 400.

```
[HttpGet("raw/{status}")]
public IActionResult GetRawStatus(int status)
{
    return StatusCode(status);
}
```

To suppress the default ProblemDetails response body you can have an empty ObjectResult with the status.

The example below generates an response without ProblemDetails for any status code.

```
    [HttpGet("object/{status}")]
    public IActionResult GetObjectStatus(int status)
    {
        return new ObjectResult(null) { StatusCode = status };
    }
```